# How can I draw children of a LinearLayout outside of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, clip

I got an LinearLayout filled with ImageViews. The ImageViews are placed like in the code below, together they are bigger than the screen and got clipped.

I implemented a function, which uses the  setX() and setY() of the LinearLayout to move it. But when I move the Layout, the clipped ImageViews don't redraw.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/intro_relativ_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            >


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/_1a"
                    />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/_1b"
                    />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/_1c"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
```

What I tried:

1. invalidate() the LinearLayout after moving it
2. set ClipChildren = false on all Layouts. After setting this, the ImageViews draw offscreen, but they ignore the LinearLayout order. They got all drawn one above the other.
3. Put the LinearLayout into a ScrollView. This works, but then i got problems with the hardware acceleration and the Views don't move smoothly.

may u got an answer